# Autosaving option using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a code for saving the opened excel file , but the challenge is that the I have more than 2 workbooks opened.

```
Sub Macro1()
  Sheets("Sheet1").Select
  Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
End Sub

Sub Autosave()
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\PCname\Desktop\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text, _
     FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

1st code create new book from the raw file on which all calculations are done. New File name is "Book1"

2nd code saves the active workbook, but doesnt save the new created book.

Could someone help me to fix this.

Comment: Someone has just gone to the effort of editing the entire code of your previous post less than an hour ago. You might at least have had the grace to format your own code this time. Would you mind editing your question to save someone else the effort?

Comment: Sorry I am a new user , don't know how this works just started only. Actually I just want to be more specific so that it will be easy for all.

Comment: This page should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566

you need to save the macro in the default excel workbook, that way it applies to each workbook, and not just the one with the macro in it.